# Referencing .NET Standard csproj project from .NET Framework traditional project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a library written against **.NET Standard 1.3** which should be compatible with the **.NET Framework 4.6.1** runtime. The library uses the new **csproj** and works fine when referenced by **.NET Core** projects.

I also have a **WPF** project on a traditional **csproj** which should be able to use this library. In **Visual Studio 2017** I managed to reference the **.NET Standard** library and it compiles without errors.

At runtime, it tries to load assemblies which are dependencies of the **.NET Standard** project and it fails with `assembly not found` exceptions. And I can see that my output folder doesn't have any of the dependencies indeed.

Is there a way to reference my library in such a way all the required dependencies are copied to the output folder (or an equivalent solution to make the **WPF** project run fine)?

**Note:** If I reference manually one by one all the missing dependencies and use runtime assembly version binding I can make it run, but I shouldn't really do this when referencing a project.

**This is the full project page:** https://github.com/UnoSD/PasswordManager

[**.NET Standard csproj**](https://github.com/UnoSD/PasswordManager/blob/master/Core/Core.csproj)

[**WPF package.config**](https://github.com/UnoSD/PasswordManager/blob/master/Paccia/packages.config)

[**WPF csproj**](https://github.com/UnoSD/PasswordManager/blob/master/Paccia/Paccia.csproj)

It currently is a **Roslyn** problem: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17639)

Comment: Can you share your files, both the netstandard and WPF project? Also, does your WPF project have a packages.config file? If so please share that too.

Comment: @natemcmaster all in GitHub, I have added the links.

Comment: You have to have the necessary dependencies in your output folder (use Copy Local), as well as correct assembly redirection in app.config.

Comment: @LexLi That's what I'm doing, but I shouldn't have to manually add the dependencies.

Comment: @Stefanod'Antonio "shouldn't" is just your opinion. Sadly the fact is that you have to.

Comment: @LexLi I'm 100% sure that's not by design. If you think it is, then post a link to the documentation stating it. You never had to do this before .NET Standard and it would be ridiculous to have to do it for all the references, you end up with a project with one class referencing thousand of packages.

Comment: Indeed, here's the Roslyn issue: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4488

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an active issue on **Roslyn**:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17639

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4488

Comment: There are even more if you use "FileNotFoundException" keyword to search across the .NET Core repos. So I don't think there would be a quick fix.

Comment: @LexLi I posted the main one and mine, others are mostly closed duplicates. They suggest a workaround, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify compiler output for .NET 4.6.1

Put line like below into your csproj in your .NET Standard library project.

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.4;net461</TargetFrameworks>
```

(that should go instead `<TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>`)

Build will produce binaries both for .NET 4.6.1 and .NET Core runtime compatible with NET Standard 1.4.

Comment: Also, I read the whole point of using .NET Standard was not to multi-target, isn't this just multi-targeting?

Comment: Indeed, targeting both I get some type collisions and it doesn't compile anymore.

Comment: Anyone figure this out yet? I want to use a .net standard library in a project that also uses net461.

Comment: And what's the issue @christopherclark? You should be able to reference .net standard from a .net461 project